# TF14054: The Encoding -2 is not valid. The client should never send this value

Tags: c#

I have been trying to add items to TFS, using a C# application for TFS. I am using the Microsoft.TeamFoundation DLLs.

When I come to create the pending add, I get the following error:

> TF14054: The Encoding -2 is not valid. The client should never send this value

```
workspace.PendAdd("C:/wsPath", true); // pend-add

if (workspace.GetPendingChangesEnumerable().Any())
{
    workspace.CheckIn(workspace.GetPendingChanges(), "comment");
}
```

I only get this problem on a colleague's machine, not on my own. The only difference is that I have the powertools installed.

I can get around the problem by using:

```
workspace.PendAdd(new string[]{"C:/wsPath"},true,
     FileType.BinaryFileType,LockLevel.Unchanged); // pend-add the build
```

Which tells it that every file is binary - not an ideal solution.

There seems to be no documentation anywhere on the internet for this error. Can someone shed light on the problem?

Comment: Kinda shooting in the dark on this, but I'm going to try to reason this out.  First, with a pending add, it appears the client sends a value to identify the character encoding for text files.  Your client sends a valid value, while your colleague's client sends -2.  -2 suggests a twos-compliment value.  Thus, I'm guessing your colleague might be running a 32-bit computer with 64-bit software installed (or vice-versa).  Basically, check that all components of this application match the bit-encoding (64 bit or 32 bit) of your client's machine.  But like I said--I'm kinda guessing here.

Comment: Gather more evidence.  Try different files, with and without a BOM.  At least [do this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms245453%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This MSDN question](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/7d37f750-a2fb-4bb3-9e0b-8abfeba067dc/opening-the-resolve-conflicts-window-programaticly?forum=tfsversioncontrol) indicates that there may be problems in the TFS API depending on the type of workspace that you are using (server workspace vs. local workspace).

Check if the working machine and the problematic machine are using different workspace types. If so, you could generally switch to whichever one does not pose problems.